# how to get the value of bootstrap dropdown menu from dropdown submenu in onclick event of jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am using boostrap dropdown menu and  submenu.On click of an element in submenu,I want to fetch both dropdown menu element(parent) and submenu element.I have written a dropdown menu click event and i am able to get the submenu.But i am struggling to find the parent elemnt of submenu.
Please help!

Html:

```
       <ul id="ddltest" class="ddlSample dropdown-menu" role="menu">

            @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.test)
            {
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="test1">
                        @item.Text

                    </a>
                    <ul class="ddlSample dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="testorder">
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">test1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">test2</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>

Jquery:

 $('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function () {

    var Submenutext = $(this).text();
    var parentmenutext = $(this).parent().closest('li');
    alert(Submenutext);
    alert(parentmenutext);


});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: shouldnt the above be working? you do parent() which is an inner li, then you do closest which takes you to the parent li

Answer (score 0):

Try this see if this work for you:

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function () {
    var Submenutext = $(this).text();
    var parentmenutext = $(this).closest('li.dropdown-submenu > a').text();
    //or  var parentmenutext = $(this).closest('ul').parent().find('a').text(); 
    alert(Submenutext );
    alert(parentmenutext);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this see if this work for you:

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function () {
    var Submenutext = $(this).text();
    var parentmenutext = $(this).closest('li.dropdown-submenu > a').text();
    alert(Submenutext);
    alert(parentmenutext);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/cvy4mapu/), with the help of these methods [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) and [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function () {
    var Submenutext = $(this).text();
    var parentmenutext = $(this).parents().eq(3).find('a').text();
    alert(Submenutext);
    alert(parentmenutext);
});
```